# Can we find eigenvalues of an operator without knowing the boundary conditions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, vectors, differential-equations, quantum-states

Imagine I have a space spanned by the two basis vectors $e_1 = sin x$ and $e_2=cos x$ and I define some inner product using $\langle f|g\rangle = \frac{1}{π}\int_0^{2\pi} f^*g dx$ and some operator $D = i \frac{d}{dx}$ and I want to solve the eigenvalue equation $Df(x) = kf(x)$, I find that the eigenvectors $f(x) = e^{-ikx}$ by solving the ode.
If I apply the D operator to my basis vectors, I find
$D e_1 = ie_2$ and $De_2 = -ie_1$ which means D has the form

$\begin{matrix} 0 & -i\\
i & 0\\
\end{matrix}$

This immediately shows that the eigenvectors are $\pm ie_1 + e_2 = e^{\pm ix}$ and the eignevalues are $k = \pm 1$.

But I don't know the boundary conditions, so how can I derive the the eigenvalues? Are these values correct or did I miss something like we need to multiply them with a constant?
If they're correct, is it possible to derive them from the differential equation alone without finding D in matrix form?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Surely saying it is spanned by $\sin$ and $\cos$ implies what the boundary conditions are (ie that they are periodic in $2\pi$?

Comment: Yeah I think you're right, this was stupid. Thanks.